# Creating parent child items

Tags: python

I have the following text and need to create a parent-child relationship between some things.

For example, whenever I encounter `start` inside another `start` its considered a child for the earlier parent so in the example `step3` is child of `step2`.

I had opened the file and using regex. I'm trying to extract the steps 
and then create a dictionary based on parent-child relationship.

The example text:

```
-----Starting Step for step1-----
text1
text2
text3
-----Ending Step for step1-----
-----Starting Step for step2-----
text4
text5
text6
-----Starting Step for step3-----
text7
text8
text9
-----Ending Step for step3-----

text10
text11
text12
-----Ending Step for step2-----
```

My code is:

```
with open('notepad_1.txt','r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        value=re.findall(r'Starting Step for (\w+)',line)
        new_value=re.findall(r'Ending Step for (\w+)',line)
        if value:
            if parent_tag_start:
                parent_tag_start[-1][parent_tag_start[-1].keys()[0]]=value[0]  
            else:
                parent_tag_start.append(value[0])
        elif new_value:
            parent_tag_start.remove(new_value[0])
```

Expected output

```
{'step1':None,step2:{step3}} # could extend up to n levels
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you overcomplicated your problem. A good idea was to use the list `parten_tag_start` to keep track of the levels you already "went down", but the way you used it was too complicated.

You simply iterate over the `parent_tag_start` list whenever you need to add another level. I updated your code to add an empty dictionary on new created levels/children. So using this code:

```
import re

parent_tag_start = []
result_dict = {}

with open('notepad_1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        value = re.findall(r'Starting Step for (\w+)', line)
        new_value = re.findall(r'Ending Step for (\w+)', line)
        if value:
            level = result_dict
            # Find the current level
            for item in parent_tag_start:
                level = level[item]
            level[value[0]] = {}  # Add an empty dict as new child

            parent_tag_start.append(value[0])
        elif new_value:
            parent_tag_start.remove(new_value[0])  # A level ended

print(result_dict)
```

This results in this output for your example text:

```
{'step1': {}, 'step2': {'step3': {}}}
```

To check for another child you can simply check if the value of the current element is an empty dictionary or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `stack` list keeping track of the last active dictionary.

As dictionaries are mutable you are actually editing the same objects regardless how you access it. So if you have

```py
new = {}
out['a'] = new
stack[-1] = new
```

Then `out['a']` and `stack[-1]` are actually the same element and you can edit it by calling either.

Here is the proposed code:

```py
import re

with open('notepad_1.txt','r') as f:
    out = {}
    stack = [out]
    for line in f.readlines():
        start=re.findall(r'Starting Step for (\w+)',line)
        end=re.findall(r'Ending Step for (\w+)',line)

        if start:
            new = dict()
            stack[-1][start[0]] = new
            # Add the new dict to the stack
            stack.append(new)
        elif end:
            # remove the last dict as it is completed
            stack.pop()      
print(out)
```

Output:

> `{'step1': {}, 'step2': {'step3': {}}}`

#### Head-up

If the file structure is invalid and contains too few end-tags, it will throw an `IndexError`.

You could still iterate afterwards over the result and replace empty dicts. `{}` with `None`, but I don't see the benefit of it.